# DOMDocument->createTextNode not to encode XML

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have XML that i need the user to be able to edit (inside a `textarea`) to his liking and then readd it to a DOMDocument Here is what i have so far.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = true;      //Formating the output
$ele = $dom->createElement("someele", "Hello");
$dom->appendChild( $ele );

$string = "<yowhatsup><noway>some text</noway></yowhatsup>";

$ele = $dom->createElement("otherxmlstuff", $string);
$dom->appendChild( $ele );
```

Now the output encodes the `$string` variable and that is not good for me as i want the user to be able to add xml as well as a string into my DOMDocument.

Could I do some pre-processing to turn text into a element as well, or am I barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Is that XML supposed to be part of the document or is supposed to be data of some element? Do you want it to be parsed along with the other XML in the document, e.g. should `getElementsByTagName('yowhatsup')` find it? Or should it be an isolated piece of data? If the first, see answers below. If the latter, search SO for how to add a CDATA section with DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DOMDocumentFragment and its [appendXML()](http://docs.php.net/domdocumentfragment.appendxml) method, e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$ele = $doc->createElement("someele", "Hello");
    $xmlstuff = $doc->createElement("otherxmlstuff");

        $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
        $fragment->appendXML("<foo>text</foo><bar>text2</bar>");
        $xmlstuff->appendChild($fragment);

    $ele->appendChild($xmlstuff);
$doc->appendChild( $ele );
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<someele>Hello<otherxmlstuff><foo>text</foo><bar>text2</bar></otherxmlstuff></someele>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) rather than an element. When you set an element's text – as you do with the [`createElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) method – it is HTML encoded. This is correct behaviour.  If you want to include arbitrary XML, use [`createDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php) and [`appendXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php):

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = true;      //Formating the output
$ele = $dom->createElement("someele", "Hello");
$dom->appendChild( $ele );

$string = "<yowhatsup><noway>some text</noway></yowhatsup>";

$frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($string);
$dom->appendChild( $frag );
```

But be **very** careful to sanitise the input that comes from your user. If you don't sanitise well, you will end up with an XSS vulnerability, allowing arbitrary content to be inserted.